# Get url of document library from REST call

Tags: document-library, office-365, rest, url

I am working with O365 SharePoint site where I need to get the name and URL for the document libraries in a site collection. I have made a rest call for it as:

https://site/_api/web/lists and select BaseTemplate = 101.

I have managed to get the name of the document library from below code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: siteUrl  + "/_api/web/lists",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {                                  
            var tempArray = data.d.results;
             $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){  
                 if(item.BaseTemplate == "101")
                 {
                    var tempArray = new Array(2);                      
                    tempArray[0]= item.Title;                      
                 }
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(error));                    
        }
```

Now, I need to get the URL of the each document library. When I access the value of

```
        item.__metadata.uri
```

it gives me a value which is a url that is not accessible otherwise. Please get me out of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to return list url you could utilize `List.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl` property.

**Some recommendations**

From performance perspective prefer server side filtering over client side one, the example below demonstrates how to query lists filtered by `BaseTemplate`:

```
/_api/Web/Lists?filter=BaseTemplate eq '101'
```

**Example**

```
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl  + "/_api/web/lists?filter=BaseTemplate eq '101'&$expand=RootFolder",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {                                  
            var lists = data.d.results;
             $.each(lists, function(i, list){  
                 var listUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
                 console.log(listUrl);  
             });
        },
        error: function(data) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(data));                    
        }
      });
```